# How to Identify element based on identifier passed as test data?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

This is my scenario.

There are one or more radio buttons. Each radio button has a unique identifier.

For eg. *radio1* for *phone number1* and *radio2* for *phone number2*.

If I pass test data as *phone number2*, I need to select *radio2*.
If I pass test data as *phone number1*, I need to select *radio1*.

The point is, sometimes one radio button is shown, and sometimes more than one radio buttons are shown in the page. Based on my input, I need to select the radio button.

If I pass test data as *phone number2*, and if *radio2* is not available, then I get element not found exception.

How can I handle this scenario?

My requirement is: if I pass *phone number1*, then a check should happen that makes sure a radio button that holds *phone number1* is available.

Comment: It's often easier to provide solution when the actual `html` is provided with the question

Comment: It does not make sense, without any knowledge of what is being tested! It would be good if we know what flow we need to test. For a scenario whether 1 radio button exists and for 2nd scenario multiple radio button exists, so that based on the requirement you call the required method which handles radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
You can try following

```
int count = driver.findElements(By.XPath(//*[contains(@id,'radio')])).size();
```

The count will show how many radio buttons are there on the Page .

On the basis of count you can perform the testing.

Same Approach u can try for PhoneNumber as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you know count of test data then try this:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'text')]"));

for(int i=0;i< testDataCount;i++){
  System.out.println(elements.get(i).getText());
}
```